# Calculate win loss ratio

Tags: r

I want to create a win/loss ratio from a dataset that has a series of winning and losing teamID's. The dataset looks something like this:

```
WTeamID LTeamID
11      12
12      13
11      13
```

Im trying to get a dataset that would look like this:

```
TeamID  WLRatio
11      1.0
12      0.5
13      0.0
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What's your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A straightforward way is to just divide the count of the first column by the count of both columns:

```
res <- table(factor(df$WTeamID, levels = unique(unlist(df)))) / table(factor(unlist(df)))

as.data.frame(res)

  Var1 Freq
1   11  1.0
2   12  0.5
3   13  0.0
```